# Upgrade to latest kotlin version error flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

When I try to run my flutter project it shows me to upgrade to latest version of kotlin but I have already upgraded to latest version of kotlin.

This is the error message:

```
The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.  
   Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin       │
│ Gradle plugin.
```

And this my build.gradle android file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23' // Define Kotlin version here

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // Use the Kotlin version here
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
    }
}
```

And this is my gradle-wrapper properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip
```

I tried to change gradle version and updated all my dependencies to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from latest plugin declaration approach of Android as you said. The issue solution to the problem was released this [official documentation of Flutter.](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply)

First of all, you check your flutter version by `flutter --version` command and if your version is under 3.16, you must change the requirements manually.